# HBaseCommonTestingUtility class not found

Tags: hbase

I am trying to setup unittests for our hbase setup. However the test is failing with the error message "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseCommonTestingUtility".

I tried adding various packages to my gradle file (in the hope of finding this elusive class). My gradle file looks like this:

```
    compile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-testing-util:1.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:1.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase:1.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:1.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-hadoop-compat:1.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-hadoop2-compat:1.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-annotations:1.1.2'
```

Any inputs on what is the magic package that contains HBaseCommonTestingUtility.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need hbase-common-1.1.2-tests.jar. In maven you specify this dependency as (note **tests** classifier):

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId> 
    <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1.2</version> 
    <classifier>tests</classifier> 
    <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
```

I am not 100% sure how this translates to gradle. Try `org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:1.1.2:tests`.